# User control communication

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page that contains a user control `ucStatusBar`. `ucStatusBar` has a public method `setStatus()`. The method simply updates an `<asp:label />` in the control with the string param passed in.

The master page content page is *Summary.aspx*.  *Summary.aspx* has a user control `ucNewEvent`.  When the form `ucNewEvent` is saved and either a success or fail code is returned, I am trying to update `ucStatusBar` with the success or fail message. I can call `ucStatusBar.setStatus("success message")` but i get a `null` reference exception at runtime when `setStatus` tries to set the `Text` property of the label b/c for some reason the `<asp:label />` is `null`.  Why would this be `null`?  Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I've been working with ASP.Net for two years and I still find the page life cycle frustrating/confusing at times.  Especially when you're talking about multiple controls across multiple pages unified by a master page.  If you still can't figure it out after some page cycle study, edit this question and post some code --- I'd love to see if we can't figure it out and learn something along the way.  I definitely need the practice.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but I think that you are trying to set the `Text` property from within the `Page_Load` event (or some function called from within it).

ASP.NET programming is all about timing, which means you really, really need to understand the [Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It's possible that you are trying to access the user controls before they have finished loading.

Typically, it's best to use the `Page_Load` event strictly for parsing the request (`Server.Request`). Get the information you need, save it to class variables, then set control properties, etc, in the [`LoadComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [`PreRender`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.prerender%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event.